# How do I subset a dataframe based on index matches to the column name of another dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I want to keep the columns of `df` if its column name matches the index of `df2`.
My code below only returns the `df.index` but I want to return the entire subset of pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = df[df.columns.intersection(df2.index)]
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with an input dataframe and a desired result output.

Comment: The exact issue is unclear, a minimal example with reproducible inputs, your current output, and the expected output would help to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to have datas from both dataframes matching with index of df2. *Correct?*

You can use [Merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to join the dataframes.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=[df2.index])
```

Comment: I only want data from the first dataframe `df` using the index name of the `df2`.

Comment: You can change how value from _'inner'_ to **_'left'_** and it will work just fine. For more information and clarity, you can refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).